# Breaking a File into Blocks

Tags: python, sha256

Working on an assignment for a self-study course that I'm taking in cryptography (I'm receiving no credit for this class). I need to compute hash values on a large file where the hash is done block by block. The thing that I am stumped on at the moment is how to break up the file into these blocks? I'm using python, which I'm very new to.

```
f = open('myfile', 'rb')
BLOCK_SIZE = 1024
m = Crypto.Hash.SHA256.new()
thisHash = ""
blocks = os.path.getsize('myfile') / BLOCK_SIZE #ignore partial last block for now

for i in Range(blocks):
    b = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
    thisHash = m.update(b.encode())
    f.seek(block_size, os.SEEK_CUR)
```

Am I approaching this correctly? The code seems to run up until the `m.update(b.encode())` line executes. I don't know if I am way off base or what to do to make this work. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

(note: as you might notice, this code doesn't really produce anything at the moment - I'm just getting some of the scaffolding set up)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to do a few things to make this example work correctly. Here are some points:

- `Crypto.Hash.SHA256.SHA256Hash.update()` (you invoke it as `m.update()`) has no return value. To pull a human-readable hash out of the object, `.update()` it a bunch of times and then call `.hexdigest()`
- You don't need to encode binary data before feeding it to the `.update()` function. Just pass the string containing the data block.
- File pointers are advanced by `file.read()`. You don't need a separate `.seek()` operation.
- `.read()` will return an empty string if you've hit EOF already. This is totally fine. Feel free just to pull in that partial block.
- Variable names are case-sensitive. `block_size` is not the same variable as `BLOCK_SIZE`.

Making these few minor adjustments, and assuming you have all the right imports, you'll be on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution would be breaking the file into blocks first and then perform hash block by block

This will break the file into chunks of 1024 bytes

```
with open(file,'rb') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(1024)
        if chunk:
            fList.append(chunk)
        else:
            numBlocks = len(fList)
            break
```

`Note: last block size may be less than 1024 bytes`

Now you can do the hash in whichever you want to.